# Trying to split a List in Java but I'm dumbfounded in indexing confusion

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a List that I need to split because it gets sent to Google translate via the API and it has a List element size limit of 1024.

Here's the code (including the debugging code I added to try and figure this out):

```
    int size   = MASTER_LINE_LIST.size();
    int third  = size / 3;
    int start1 = 0;
    int end1   = start1 + third;
    int start2 = end1 + 1;
    int end2   = start2 + third;
    int start3 = end2 + 1;
    int end3   = size - 1;

    String msg1 = "start1 = "   + start1    + "\n" +
                  "end1   = "   + end1      + "\n\n" +
                  "start2 = "   + start2    + "\n" +
                  "end2   = "   + end2      + "\n\n" +
                  "start3 = "   + start3    + "\n" +
                  "end3   = "   + end3      + "\n\n";

    List<String> lineListSub0 = MASTER_LINE_LIST.subList(start1, end1);
    List<String> lineListSub1 = MASTER_LINE_LIST.subList(start2, end2);
    List<String> lineListSub2 = MASTER_LINE_LIST.subList(start3, end3);

    int mllSize = MASTER_LINE_LIST.size();
    int ll0Size = lineListSub0.size();
    int ll1Size = lineListSub1.size();
    int ll2Size = lineListSub2.size();
    int llTotal = ll0Size + ll1Size + ll2Size;
    String msg2 =  "Master list size = "            + mllSize + "\n\n" +
                     "sublist 1 size = "            + ll0Size + "\n" +
                     "sublist 2 size = "            + ll1Size + "\n" +
                     "sublist 3 size = "            + ll2Size + "\n\n" +
                     "total size of sublists = "    + llTotal;

    System.out.println(msg1);
    System.out.println(msg2);
```

Here is the output from this code:

```
start1 = 0
end1   = 949

start2 = 950
end2   = 1899

start3 = 1900
end3   = 2846


Master list size = 2847

sublist 1 size = 949
sublist 2 size = 949
sublist 3 size = 946

total size of sublists = 2844
```

As you can see, the original List has 2,847 elements, yet the sum of the sizes of the subLists adds up to 2,844 ... I somehow lost three elements and I can't seem to find them because when I look at my start and end indexes that I use for the splits, they appear to me to be a cumulative series of numbers from 0 to 2846, as the start index of the next sublist is the end index of the previous sub-list plus 1 ... it looks right to me but why is it not adding up? Each sub-list SHOULD contain exactly 949 elements ... yet that third one doesn't ... but if I expand the boundaries of the indexes, I'll either get repeating data, or I'll go out of bounds.

What am I missing?

Comment: The end index is *exclusive*, that means the element at that particular index is not part of your sub-list. You're creating 3 sub-lists like this, so you're missing 3 indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `subList()` does not include the `toIndex`, which means that in the following `subList()` you need to start at the `toIndex` of the previous `subList()`.

```java
int size   = MASTER_LINE_LIST.size();
int third  = size / 3;
int start1 = 0;
int end1   = start1 + third;
int start2 = end1;
int end2   = start2 + third;
int start3 = end2;
int end3   = size - 1;
```

Comment: Well there's something I didn't know ... that explains it.

Comment: Java documentation is usually pretty good, for `subList()` you can find it at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-. It is always beneficial to take a look at it when you are using something new ;)